# SQL INSERT INTO SELECT Statement between two different databases

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

sometimes I need to move data from one database table to another table in different database. These tables are identic. So I am trying to make program in C# Winforms, but I cant figure it out. 
I think that I should use this:

```
INSERT INTO table2
    SELECT *
    FROM table1
    WHERE condition;
```

But how can I execute this sql command when I need two connections? Or what is the right approach?

**EDIT:** They aren't on same server. Any other option than throught Linked servers?

Comment: If you need to do this more than a trivial amount: purchase a tool designed to synchronise data between databases. They may appear to cost a lot, but that will be cheaper than your time.

Answer (score 3):

If two databases have the same server, then you can do :

```
INSERT INTO [dbname].[schema].table2 (<column list >)
     SELECT * 
     FROM [dbname].[schema].table1
     WHERE condition;
```

Comment: Or, if on another server: linked servers.

Comment: They aren't on same server. I forget to mention. Is linked servers the only one possibility?

Comment: @Kali26. . . Yes `linked servers` could be possible solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Yogesh's answer, if the databases are on separate servers, you will need to [set up a linked server](http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/how-to-add-a-linked-server)